# How to commit code when using Composer?

Tags: git, composer-php

**Scenario**
I have added my `composer.json` file and installed my dependancies. In this scenario we'll assume I've installed my dependancies into `/Plugin`.

Now I find a bug in one of my packages and I would like to fix it and update my dependancy.

So I make the required changes in my code.

**Issue**
So now I have changed files in my dependancy and I can't commit them, because my `.gitignore` ignores my `/Plugin` folder, because it is being managed with Composer.

**Question**
How do I go about being able to commit my code from here to the correct repository? I would like to avoid using Git submodules because I recently converted my codebase from submodule to Composer, to give me greater flexibility.

Ideally I would like to make my changes, commit and tag my code and then push it to it's remote upstream. Then simply update my `composer.json` to the new tag.

**Environment**
 - [PHP 5.5.13](http://php.net/)
 - [Git 2.0.0](http://git-scm.com/)
 - [Composer 28c65b5425f7f8722c260e3787b74c1ea6b37e3b](http://getcomposer.org/)

Comment: Seems there is no tag for Composer yet :)

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two ways to integrate a library into the main project: `--prefer-dist` or `--prefer-source`. The first tries to download a complete package if Composer knows where to find it, while the second tries to checkout from the repository (should always work because Composer usually knows about the repository).

If you include a branch like "dev-master", Composer always checks out the repository.

Consider you have a "yourownvendor/library", that would be in "Plugin/yourownvendor/library" - and if Composer cloned a repository, if you go into that library, you can directly work in it, i.e. commit files and push (when using Git) or just commit (when using SVN). Because you ignore the whole tree, Git will not detect any repositories in the subtree as submodules (don't try to use them when using Composer, always ignore that path), and using any Git command will just treat the library repos as a standalone repo.

Very easy indeed. Pay attention however that you commit all your code before using any Composer command because Composer might delete uncommitted changes.